# linq to sql wildcard on numeric column

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, wildcard

In SQL i can do something like this :

```
select  * from Table1 where Col1 like '%'
```

I'm trying to this in linq like this :

```
from p in Table1
where SqlMethods.Like(p.Col1, "%")
select  new { p.Col1}
```

But it's not working because it's expecting Col1 to be int.

The reason i'm doing this is because i'm trying to build a search form and must use wildcards for the parameters that aren't completed (some are strings, some are numeric).

Comment: how do you do a LIKE on numeric fields in regular SQL? I think you are making a thinking-error here.

Comment: What do you expect from a `LIKE` on a numerical column??

Comment: @Bazzz - yup, believe it or not. SQL uses an implicit cast on the ints to char. Likely to wind up with Scans however.

Comment: yeah, that might be the problem as it is slowing the query a lot

Comment: if you have another suggestion on how can i make a query with multiple parameters without using a wildcard on numeric fields that would be great

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about, for integer values, you specify a range and a predicate that specifies the value must be greater than minimum/less than maximum instead?  This seems more intuitive to me than doing a string comparison on a numeric field.

Comment: This would perform much better than converting the column to a string, because this can cause a table scan. If the table is big enough, well.... you will be in trouble.

Comment: the table it's 600k rows, this method is working pretty well but visibly slower that a direct equal

Comment: You could also just ignore the predicate for the columns that can be wild cards.  If you don't need to apply a constraint, there really isn't a reason to have one.  such as "from p in Table1 select  new { p.Col1 }"

Comment: can you build dynamic constructs in linq ? i'm gonna research it as this would be the fastest method.

Comment: can you please give an example as i'm trying to pass the condition as string `string dynamicQuery= "p => p.Col1==10919";` and then use it in the linq query `.Where(dynamicQuery)`   and it's not working

Comment: Expression<Func<WhateverPIs,bool>> dynamicQuery = p => p.Col1==10919;

Answer (score 2):

Why not try converting to string then?

```
from p in Table1
where SqlMethods.Like(p.Col1.ToString(), "%")
select  new { p.Col1}
```

Comment: Nice thinking but what is it supposed to match? now it matches any numeric value and returns everything. :)

Comment: He's talking generically.  He's implementing a simple search and would like to match what I can only assume to be a search query, i.e. `..."%" + searchTerm.Text + "%"...`

Comment: Also, like @Simeon mentions, he can easily use the .Contains() method for the same functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Hm. Like this?

```
from p in Table1
where p.Col1.ToString().Contains("foo")
select new { p.Col1}
```

Exchange Contains with BeginsWith/StartsWith as the LIKE functionality can... or use RegExp if it's a more complex expression.